# Add a new axis to the right/left/top-right of an axis

Tags: matplotlib

How do you add an axis to the outside of another axis, keeping it within the figure as a whole?  `legend` and `colorbar` both have this capability, but implemented in rather complicated (and for me, hard to reproduce) ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subplots command to achieve this, this can be as simple as `py.subplot(2,2,1)` where the first two numbers describe the geometry of the plots (2x2) and the third is the current plot number. In general it is better to be explicit as in the following example

```
import pylab as py

# Make some data
x = py.linspace(0,10,1000)
cos_x = py.cos(x)
sin_x = py.sin(x)

# Initiate a figure, there are other options in addition to figsize
fig = py.figure(figsize=(6,6))

# Plot the first set of data on ax1
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(x,sin_x)

# Plot the second set of data on ax2
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.plot(x,cos_x)

# This final line can be used to adjust the subplots, if uncommentted  it will remove  all white space
#fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.13, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.12,hspace=0.0,wspace=0.0)
```

[image: Produces this image]

Notice that this means things like `py.xlabel` may not work as expected since you have two axis. Instead you need to specify `ax1.set_xlabel("..")` this makes the code easier to read.

More examples can be found [here.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)